# Mongodb aggregate, How to count documents by interval criteria?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

my MongoDB document looks like this:

```
{StatCode : "...", LoadTime  : "..."}
```

For example, the data might look like this:

```
+-----+----------+------------+
| _id | StatCode |  LoadTime  |
+-----+----------+------------+
|   1 |      200 |      0,345 |
|   2 |      200 |      0,234 |
|   3 |      200 |      0,396 |
|   4 |      200 |      1,234 |
|   5 |      200 |      2,564 |
|   6 |      200 |      0,437 |
|   7 |      301 |      0,523 |
|   8 |      301 |      0,628 |
|   9 |      301 |      0,712 |
|  10 |      200 |      1,784 | 
+-----+----------+------------+
```

I want to get the count group by LoadTime values like this :
Slowest (more than 2), Slow (between 1 and 2), Medium (between 0,5 and 1) and Fast (below 0,5)

With Data example, the result would look like this:

```
+----------+-------+
| Info_id  | Count |
+----------+-------+
| Slowest  |     1 |
| Slow     |     2 |
| Medium   |     3 |
| Fast     |     4 |
+----------+-------+
```

**Edit:** Remark Neil Lunn, sample documents from MongoDB

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "LoadTime" : NumberLong(345),
    "StatCode" : 200
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "LoadTime" : NumberLong(234),
    "StatCode" : 200
}
....
{
    "_id" : 9,
    "LoadTime" : NumberLong(712),
    "StatCode" : 301
}
{
    "_id" : 10,
    "LoadTime" : NumberLong( 1784),
    "StatCode" : 200
}
```

How can I accomplish this using the MongoDB aggregation framework?

Comment: Can you please **not** show us youy MySQL output and actually show us your sample documents from MongoDB. It will help in case there is a data format problem. Also can you include in your edit details of anything you have tried or say simply that you do not know where to start, if that is the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you do want is the [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator and quite a few nested conditions with [$and](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/#exp._S_and). But this should give you exactly what you want.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group": {
      "_id": {"$cond": [
          {"$gte": ["$LoadTime", 2000] },
          "Slowest",                                   // return "Slowest" where true
          {"$cond": [
              {"$and": [
                  {"$lt": ["$LoadTime", 2000] },
                  {"$gte": ["$LoadTime", 1000] }
              ]},
              "Slow",                                  // then "Slow" here where true
              {"$cond": [
                  {"$and": [
                      {"$lt": ["$LoadTime", 1000] },
                      {"$gte": ["$LoadTime", 500 ] }
                  ]},
                  "Medium",                            // then "Medium" where true
                  "Fast"                               // and finally "Fast" < 500
              ]}
          ]}
      ]},
      "count": {"$sum": 1}
    }},
    {"$sort": { "count": 1 }}
])
```

As your time is **whole** milliseconds you can see why I asked for the edit.

So as **$cond** is a [*ternary*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary) operator, it takes three arguments being:

- A condition to evaluate which returns a **boolean**
- A return value where the condition is **true**
- A return value where the condition is **false**

Therefore the idea is that you **nest** the conditions throughout, moving to the *next* test on **false** until you have found a condition to match, and an value to return.

The **$and** part is a array of **conditions** to include. This gives you the *ranges*. So in the longest parts:

```
          {"$cond": [                             // Evaluate here
              {"$and": [                          // Within the range of the next 2
                  {"$lt": ["$LoadTime", 2000] },
                  {"$gte": ["$LoadTime", 1000] }
              ]},
              "Slow",                            // true condition - return
              {"$cond": [                        // false - move to next eval
```

Cascading through you are left with "Fast" for `times` under 500 milliseconds.

Each of these `keys` is emitted to the group and we just `{ $sum: 1 }` to get a count as they are grouped together.

If you need that in your own language implementation, the whole `pipeline` content within

> `aggregate(..)`

is just JSON, so you can parse that into your native data structure if translating by hand eludes you, or if like me you're just lazy.

### EDIT

Due to the **comments** it seems necessary to explain the **form** of the presented query. So here the edit addendum for clarification.

When **learning** use of the aggregation pipeline, and indeed **good practice** for writing out and *testing* a complex series of stages or logic, I find that it useful to **visualise** the results by implementing parts *one step at a time*. So in the case of writing such a thing my **first** step would be as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group": {
      "_id": {"$cond": [
          {"$gte": ["$LoadTime", 2000] },
          "Slowest",
          null
       ]}
    }}
])
```

Now that would give me the count of "Slowest" as I would expect and then *bucket* everything else into `null`. So there is a stage where I see the results so far. But when *testing* I would actually do something like this before moving on to build up a chain:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group": {
      "_id": {"$cond": [
          {"$and": [
              {"$lt": ["$LoadTime", 2000] },
              {"$gte": ["$LoadTime", 1000] }
          ]},
          "Slow",
          null
      ]}
    }}
])
```

So I am just getting the results for "Slow" (*between* 2000 and 1000) with everything else in the `null` bucket. So my overall count remains the same.

In the **final** query, as was pointed out, in a [*ternary*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary) condition that is nested such as this, the **first** stage has **already** evaluated `false` for the items being tested by the **next** operator. This means that they are **not** *greater than* the value which was already tested in the **first** stage, and that obviates the need to test for that condition so this **could** be written as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group": {
      "_id": {"$cond": [
          {"$gte": ["$LoadTime", 2000] },       // Caught everything over 2000
          "Slowest",
          {"$cond": [
              {"$gte": ["$LoadTime", 1000] }    // Catch things still over 1000
              "Slow",
              {"$cond": [                       // Things under 1000 go here

              // and so on
```

And that *short circuits* the evaluation as there is no **real** need to test for things that won't come through to the next logical condition.

So **purely** for *visual reasons* and for sheer laziness of *cut and paste* logic, we end up with the expanded form using the **$and** condition to *wrap* the range. But for those **not used to** the usage of the [*ternary*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary) form there is a *clear visual cue* that the results being matched in this phase will **fall between** the values of `2000ms` and `1000ms`,and so on,  which is what you want as a result in each range.

As I said, unnecessary to have because of how the logic works, but it *was* a development phase, and is **clear** to the people who are yet to *get their heads around* usage of the [*ternary*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary) form that **$cond** provides.

Comment: @PapyRef Glad it helped. Note that the same principals apply to the [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator if you might otherwise need to **tag** entries for some other kind of analysis. Aggregate is your friend, and worthwhile to learn all the tricks.

Comment: you can significantly simplify the syntax by removing the unnecessary tests.  if x is >= 10 then something; else <here x cannot be >=10 again so you can make do with a single condition in each "else" and remove all the $and's.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky You could indeed. But of course there is no overhead involved and as a learning case, I find it easier for people to get their heads around if conditions look like they expect. But well spotted by you.

Comment: I think for learning purposes it's simpler to understand something that maps to typical programming syntax: if (a>10) { } else if (a>5) else if (a>2) etc.   Adding extra conditionals inside else if would likely be more confusing to people than not.  IMHO, of course.

Comment: @Asya Kamsky: for learning purposes, could you rewrite this Mongo query with typical programming syntax: if (...) { } else if (...) else if (...).

Comment: No, but you can use {$cond expression that way, the way Neil did, I was just pointing out that some of the tests he has in the $and clauses are unnecessary.

Comment: @PapyRef See the expanded explanation on the answer that explains all these comments.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I didn't set out to write a dissertation on this. But I have explained my reasoning and shown the short circuit syntax in an additional section to the answer. I hope that makes you happy.