# How to write mongo shell commands into the equivalent C# statements

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to use the aggregate function to get a count of popular tags in a certain collection. I want to simply execute pure MongoDB queries via MongoDb for Windows & .Net(C# 4.0) driver.

Here is the mongo shell query, I wish to execute (see [Mongodb aggregate, How to count documents by interval criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965585/mongodb-aggregate-how-to-count-documents-by-interval-criteria))?

```
collection.aggregate({
    $group: { "_id": { $cond: [{$gte: ["$LoadTime", 2000]}, "Slowest", 
                                {$cond: [ {$and: [{$lt: ["$LoadTime", 2000] },{$gte: ["$LoadTime", 1000]}]}, "Slow", 
                                    {$cond: [{$and: [{$lt: ["$LoadTime", 1000]}, {$gte: ["$LoadTime", 500 ]} ]},"Medium","Fast"]}
                                        ]}
                              ]},
              "count": {$sum: 1}   
            }
})
```

I am not sure how can i do this. 
Perhaps with call Database.RunCommand("TheCommand") or bson_xxxx methods but I don't know how.
Is it possible to execute pure MongoDB queries via .Net (C# 4.0) driver?

Comment: The C# driver supports aggregation since version 1.8 (if I remember correctly). [Mikael Koskinen](http://dotnet.dzone.com/users/mikoskin) has a great post on the subject: [MongoDB Aggregation Framework Examples in C#](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/mongodb-aggregation-framework).

Answer (score 0):

For aggregation, use MongoCollection's IEnumerable Aggregate(AggregateArgs args). FYI this is the version in 1.9rc, the prior overloads of Aggregate have been deprecated in favor of using the new AggregateArgs.

Aggregate doesn't have fluent building support in the c# driver (yet), so you're basically creating BsonDocument instances for each stage in your pipeline and passing that array of documents to AggregateArgs.Pipeline.

Under the "hood" this is using CommandDocument, but I don't see much benefit to use that directly when the driver already takes care of that via MongoCollection's internal RunAggregateCommand.

Comment: And if I do MongoDb function with this MongoDB querie and call the function in C# via MongoDatabase.Eval() method?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid building the aggregation query with the .net BsonDocument type?

Comment: Yes. I write & test this query in Mongo Shell.I wondered if it would be possible to use this query as it in C #. I would avoid to rewrite the query so as not to repeat tests. This does not appear easy to recode the query with the .net BsonDocument type.